# corosync is not in sync

Tags: linux, cluster, high-availability, corosync

Could you please help out show me how to form a cluster?

corosync & pacemaker are used. two nodes 
rac0 ip 192.168.0.140 & 
rac1 ip 192.168.0.142
They are not shown in each other.
They are not connected.

`[ryan@rac1 cluster]$ sudo pcs status corosync
[sudo] password for ryan:`

### Membership information

```
Nodeid      Votes Name
     2          1 rac1 (local)
```

========================================================

`[ryan@rac0 ~]$ sudo pcs status corosync
[sudo] password for ryan:`

### Membership information

```
Nodeid      Votes Name
     1          1 rac0 (local)
```

=======================================================

`nodelist {
        node {
                ring0_addr: rac0
                nodeid: 1
        }
        node {
                ring0_addr: rac1
                nodeid: 2
        }
}`

=======================================================

`[ryan@rac1 corosync]$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6`

`192.168.0.140  rac0
192.168.0.142   rac1`

=======================================================================

`[ryan@rac0 ~]$ sudo cat /etc/hosts
[sudo] password for ryan:`
`127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6`

`192.168.0.140  rac0
192.168.0.142   rac1`

=================================================================================

`[ryan@rac0 ~]$ sudo tail -20 /var/log/cluster/corosync.log
Mar 17 17:52:58 [1588] rac0       crmd:     info: crm_timer_popped:     PEngine Recheck Timer (I_PE_CALC) just popped (900000ms)
Mar 17 17:52:58 [1588] rac0       crmd:   notice: do_state_transition:  State transition S_IDLE -> S_POLICY_ENGINE [ input=I_PE_CALC cause=C_TIMER_POPPED origin=crm_timer_popped ]
Mar 17 17:52:58 [1588] rac0       crmd:     info: do_state_transition:  Progressed to state S_POLICY_ENGINE after C_TIMER_POPPED
Mar 17 17:52:58 [1587] rac0    pengine:     info: process_pe_message:   Input has not changed since last time, not saving to disk
Mar 17 17:52:58 [1587] rac0    pengine:   notice: cluster_status:   We do not have quorum - fencing and resource management disabled
Mar 17 17:52:58 [1587] rac0    pengine:    error: unpack_resources:     Resource start-up disabled since no STONITH resources have been defined
Mar 17 17:52:58 [1587] rac0    pengine:    error: unpack_resources:     Either configure some or disable STONITH with the stonith-enabled option
Mar 17 17:52:58 [1587] rac0    pengine:    error: unpack_resources:     NOTE: Clusters with shared data need STONITH to ensure data integrity
Mar 17 17:52:58 [1587] rac0    pengine:     info: determine_online_status_fencing:  Node rac0 is active
Mar 17 17:52:58 [1587] rac0    pengine:     info: determine_online_status:  Node rac0 is online
Mar 17 17:52:58 [1587] rac0    pengine:   notice: stage6:   Delaying fencing operations until there are resources to manage
Mar 17 17:52:58 [1587] rac0    pengine:  warning: stage6:   Node rac1 is unclean!
Mar 17 17:52:58 [1587] rac0    pengine:   notice: stage6:   Cannot fence unclean nodes until quorum is attained (or no-quorum-policy is set to ignore)
Mar 17 17:52:58 [1587] rac0    pengine:  warning: process_pe_message:   Calculated Transition 2: /var/lib/pacemaker/pengine/pe-warn-8.bz2
Mar 17 17:52:58 [1587] rac0    pengine:   notice: process_pe_message:   Configuration ERRORs found during PE processing.  Please run "crm_verify -L" to identify issues.
Mar 17 17:52:58 [1588] rac0       crmd:     info: do_state_transition:  State transition S_POLICY_ENGINE -> S_TRANSITION_ENGINE [ input=I_PE_SUCCESS cause=C_IPC_MESSAGE origin=handle_response ]
Mar 17 17:52:58 [1588] rac0       crmd:     info: do_te_invoke:     Processing graph 2 (ref=pe_calc-dc-1426585978-13) derived from /var/lib/pacemaker/pengine/pe-warn-8.bz2
Mar 17 17:52:58 [1588] rac0       crmd:   notice: run_graph:    Transition 2 (Complete=0, Pending=0, Fired=0, Skipped=0, Incomplete=0, Source=/var/lib/pacemaker/pengine/pe-warn-8.bz2): Complete
Mar 17 17:52:58 [1588] rac0       crmd:     info: do_log:   FSA: Input I_TE_SUCCESS from notify_crmd() received in state S_TRANSITION_ENGINE
Mar 17 17:52:58 [1588] rac0       crmd:   notice: do_state_transition:  State transition S_TRANSITION_ENGINE -> S_IDLE [ input=I_TE_SUCCESS cause=C_FSA_INTERNAL origin=notify_crmd ]`

===========================================================================

`[ryan@rac1 cluster]$ sudo tail -20 corosync.log
[sudo] password for ryan: 
Mar 17 18:08:37 [1345] rac1 pacemakerd:     info: pcmk_quorum_notification:     State of node rac0[1] is still unknown
Mar 17 18:08:37 [1320] rac1 corosync notice  [MAIN  ] Completed service synchronization, ready to provide service.
Mar 17 18:08:37 [1347] rac1        cib:     info: crm_cs_flush:     Sent 2 CPG messages  (0 remaining, last=2901): OK (1)
Mar 17 18:08:37 [1347] rac1        cib:     info: cib_process_request:  Completed cib_modify operation for section nodes: OK (rc=0, origin=rac1/crmd/5800, version=0.4.8)
Mar 17 18:08:37 [1347] rac1        cib:     info: cib_process_request:  Completed cib_modify operation for section status: OK (rc=0, origin=rac1/crmd/5801, version=0.4.8)
Mar 17 18:08:38 [1352] rac1       crmd:     info: pcmk_quorum_notification:     Membership 5812: quorum still lost (1)
Mar 17 18:08:38 [1352] rac1       crmd:     info: pcmk_quorum_notification:     State of node rac0[1] is still unknown
Mar 17 18:08:38 [1320] rac1 corosync notice  [TOTEM ] A new membership (192.168.0.142:5812) was formed. Members
Mar 17 18:08:38 [1352] rac1       crmd:     info: do_update_node_cib:   Node update for rac0 cancelled: no state, not seen yet
Mar 17 18:08:38 [1352] rac1       crmd:     info: crm_cs_flush:     Sent 0 CPG messages  (1 remaining, last=1461): Try again (6)
Mar 17 18:08:38 [1347] rac1        cib:     info: cib_process_request:  Forwarding cib_modify operation for section nodes to master (origin=local/crmd/5804)
Mar 17 18:08:38 [1320] rac1 corosync notice  [QUORUM] Members[1]: 2
Mar 17 18:08:38 [1347] rac1        cib:     info: crm_cs_flush:     Sent 0 CPG messages  (1 remaining, last=2901): Try again (6)
Mar 17 18:08:38 [1345] rac1 pacemakerd:     info: pcmk_quorum_notification:     Membership 5812: quorum still lost (1)
Mar 17 18:08:38 [1347] rac1        cib:     info: cib_process_request:  Forwarding cib_modify operation for section status to master (origin=local/crmd/5805)
Mar 17 18:08:38 [1345] rac1 pacemakerd:     info: pcmk_quorum_notification:     State of node rac0[1] is still unknown
Mar 17 18:08:38 [1320] rac1 corosync notice  [MAIN  ] Completed service synchronization, ready to provide service.
Mar 17 18:08:38 [1347] rac1        cib:     info: crm_cs_flush:     Sent 2 CPG messages  (0 remaining, last=2903): OK (1)
Mar 17 18:08:38 [1347] rac1        cib:     info: cib_process_request:  Completed cib_modify operation for section nodes: OK (rc=0, origin=rac1/crmd/5804, version=0.4.8)
Mar 17 18:08:38 [1347] rac1        cib:     info: cib_process_request:  Completed cib_modify operation for section status: OK (rc=0, origin=rac1/crmd/5805, version=0.4.8)
[ryan@rac1 cluster]$`